# navbar css being over-ridden by bootstrap.css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a fixed navbar that works perfectly (uses `navbar.css`). But when I add in the `bootstrap.css` required for another element on my page, the navbar breaks.  Here's what I've tried to fix the conflict:

- referenced `navbar.css` after the `bootstrap.css` file
- added `!important` to every item in `navbar.css` and surrounded the link reference with `<!-------------------->`
- this other element doesn't utilize the entire `bootstrap.css` file, so I've used firebug to eliminate all unused css (down to < 500 lines of expanded CSS)
- gone through my modified `bootstrap.css` file line by line and deleted any references to my navbar (nav tags etc)

But the navbar still breaks.  Here's the code for the navbar and my css:

**HTML**

```
<nav class='sidebar sidebar-menu-collapsed'>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='#'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-align-justify  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" id='justify-icon'></i></span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='myshares.php' title='My Archives'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-archive fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>My Archives</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='sharedwithme.php' title='Shared w/ Me'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-inbox  fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>Shared w/ Me</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="active">
      <a class='expandable' href='#' title='Add a Share'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>Add Share</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='tools.html' title='Tools'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>Tools</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='howitworks.html' title='How this Works'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-question fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>How This Works</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class='expandable' href='logout.php' title='Logout'>
        <span><i class="fa fa-power-off fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
        <span class='expanded-element'>Logout</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css"; 
@import "https://www.sonoclipshare.com/public/bootstrap.css";
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}

nav.sidebar-menu-collapsed {
  width: 34px;
}

nav.sidebar-menu-expanded {
  width: 116px;
}

nav.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #0099ff;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: left;
}

nav.sidebar a#justify-icon {
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
}

nav.sidebar a#logout-icon {
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-style: normal;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}

nav.sidebar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

nav.sidebar ul li {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 3px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

nav.sidebar ul li a.expandable {
  outline: 0;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav.sidebar ul li a.expandable:hover {
  color: #bbbbbb;
}

nav.sidebar ul li a.expandable span.expanded-element {
  margin-left: 2px;
  display: none;
  font-size: 11px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 2px;
}

nav.sidebar ul li.active {
  background: none repeat scroll 0 0 black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 4px;
}

nav.sidebar ul li.active a.expandable {
  color: white;
}

nav.sidebar ul li.active a.expandable:hover {
  color: white;
}

#justify-icon {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.fa-power-off {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function expandMyMenu() {
    $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed").addClass("sidebar-menu-expanded");
  };

  function collapseMyMenu() {
    $("nav.sidebar").removeClass("sidebar-menu-expanded").addClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed");
  };

  function showMenuTexts() {
    $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").show();
    $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").css('display', 'inline');
  };

  function hideMenuTexts() {
    $("nav.sidebar ul a span.expanded-element").hide();
  };
  $("#justify-icon").click(function(e) {
    if ($("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-collapsed")) {
      expandMyMenu();
      showMenuTexts();
      $(this).css({
        color: "#000"
      });
    } else if ($("nav.sidebar").hasClass("sidebar-menu-expanded")) {
      collapseMyMenu();
      hideMenuTexts();
      $(this).css({
        color: "#FFF"
      });
    }
  });
});
```

If I remove the offending line `@import "https://www.sonoclipshare.com/public/bootstrap.css";` the navbar looks like it's supposed to.  Here's a [codepen](http://codepen.io/utnuc/pen/NAoWKO) to play around with.  I left out the 500 lines of `bootstrap.css` here for space.  Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c2chzxxa/2/) with all the css

Answer (score 0):

The offending line, is that just a cdn for the bootstrap css? Try import it from the official source by placing this in the head section of your code;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Adding this line, and the full bootstrap css breaks my menu just the same.  It can be seen by adding that line to the codepen above.

Answer (score 0):

I removed this section of css

```
nav.sidebar-menu-collapsed { 
  width: 34px;
}
```

and the navbar looked better.

Comment: I would also suggest following A. Cawlan's suggestion and using the preferred CDN source.

Comment: Agree, it does look better.  But there are still changes to the navbar from original.  Icons are smaller, text now wraps when the navbar is expanded.  I need the navbar to be untouched, since I use it throughout the entire site.

Comment: can you create a JSFiddle with your code that we can edit your code. You only provided the navbar code so we can't tall what else is broken.

Comment: I'm a little confused. Is this jsfiddle supposed to be how you want it to be with bootstrap.css because the text is currently wrapping. Can you post the code you refer to as, original, so I know what you want it to stay like. I will then add bootstrap.css and debug

Comment: There's a comment in the CSS on that jsfiddle. Everything below that line is what I need from bootstrap, it breaks my menu.  If you remove that css you can see how it's supposed to look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I was able to narrow down the css that my other code uses out of bootstrap and only include that.  Still not 100% sure what part of bootstrap was affecting my code, but it was a simple process of elimination that got me to my answer. Brute force strikes again. Thanks for everyone's suggestions.